# Laravel - log() expects parameter 1 to be float, array given

Tags: laravel

I am trying to print the content of a json request:

```
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->json()->all();
        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

First I tried to print the content to a file with this:

```
$data = $request->json()->all();
Info($data);
```

It writes this to the log:

```
[2019-06-14 10:43:51] local.ERROR: log() expects parameter 1 to be float, array given {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): log() expects parameter 1 to be float, array given at C:\\Users\\User 1\\Coding\\data-service\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\FileController.php:39)
[stacktrace]
```

**Update:**

I'm using Log:debug from Jerodev's answer but it still doesn't work.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $data = $request->json()->all();
   //\Log::info($data);
   Log::debug($data);
   return response()->json($data);
}
```

Log file:

```
local.ERROR: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Log' not found {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\Log' not found at ...
```

I've included the class like this:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Log;
```

---

Without the logging the response to the request is an empty array:

```
[]
```

How can I send a response this and log it?

```
{
  test: 123,
  debug: [...] <- $data here
}
```

**JSON request:**

```
{
    filename: "test1.jpeg"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually calling the PHP [`log()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.log.php) function, which calculates the natural logarithm and indeed expects a parameter of type float.

To [write log messages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/logging#writing-log-messages) in Laravel, you need to use the Log class.

```
Log::debug($data);
```

Comment: It writes this to the file: local.ERROR: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Log' not found.... yet I've got this: use App\Http\Controllers\Log;

Comment: I'm using this now: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log; ... and it works

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `\Log::info($data)` instead of `Log()` function, which is a PHP function that takes a float as param.

Also you can get the `$data` by just using `$request->all()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the contents of `$data`, then consider using `print_r($data);` or `var_dump($data)`. The latter will print a good-looking stack trace if you have the [xdebug extention](https://xdebug.org/) enabled.